# How to retrieve data in delta using REST API from HP QC? Can we configure it to push data to an endpoint whenever there is a cahnge?

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-alm

How to retrieve data in delta (only new data compared to last retrieval) using REST API  from HP QC? Can we configure it to push data to an endpoint whenever there is a change?

Answer (score 1):

The REST API does not support returning only data that has changed since the last retrieval.  So long as you track what you last retrieved, it will be relatively easy for you to filter out what did not change.

The REST API is also there to only respond to request.  It does not push any information.  There is the HP Synchronizer that you can use if you're trying to sync data between two systems.  You can use the workflow engine of QC to execute code when items change.